# Global state in multiprocessing

Tags: python, initialization, multiprocessing

I have found that when importing modules and using multiprocessing at the same time, strange things start to happen. Take for example:

```
# -------------------------
# main.py
# -------------------------
import multiprocessing
import foo

def bar(a):
    foo.test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    pool.map(bar, [1] * 15)

# ----------------------------
# foo.py
# ----------------------------
import api  # Note the indirect import.

def test():
    print(api.a)

# ----------------------------
# api.py
# ----------------------------
print("Imported")
a = 5
```

For me this example outputs something like:

```
Imported
Imported
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
Imported
5
5
5
5
```

Note that the module `api` is being imported (i.e. executed) multiple times. How could I avoid this? I want to run the code inside module `api` exactly once (like static initialization in C), and I want the resulting states (in this case `api.a`) to be accessible from the other processes - but only initialized once.

In the real use case, I take sensitive input from the user in the `api` module and I want to take that user input **exactly once**. Currently the user has to input his data once per Process executed by the Pool - every time the module is imported.

Comment: please clarify what parts of the code lie in which module. I assume the code above is not in the same file.

Comment: @Pynchia I add bigger comments to where which file begins

Comment: OK thank you (BTW, comments start with #). Then explain what you intend to do. The behaviour you get is exactly what you should expect from the given scenario. The problem is what are you trying to achieve/why do you need to do it that way?

Comment: @Pynchia, oops, added the comments in the browser.., anyways, I expanded what I would expect to happen. Initialized once, accessible everywhere. Btw, I'm not *bound* to using multiprocessing but I want several threads

Comment: For me it works just fine, I only get one "Imported" printed. And it makes sense: First, `main.py` imports `foo` exactly once, which in turn imports `api` exactly once as well. Initialization is now complete. After this, the subprocesses are launched. Each subprocess inherits the stack of the parent process. No further importing happens (nor is needed, since each subprocess now has access to `foo` as well as `bar`).

Comment: @Velimir, make the computation of `test()` a little bit more expensive, it may just be that no subprocesses are being launched because there is not enough delay

Answer (score 0):

Every process has it's own interpreter instance, that's why your `api` module imported several times. (New process start every time `Imported` has been printed).

More about this in [official documentatioin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: That is an explanation for the problem, but doesn't really solve it.

Comment: Ask user input in main process, then give data to your pool.